# Renaming multiple columns using their index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

How can i rename multiple columns of a dataframe using their index? 
For example i want to rename the columns at positions 5,6,7,8 to 'five','six','seven','eight' respectively. I don't want to enter the keys in the dictionary individually.

Comment: I meant can i enter keys like[4:9] then have another list of new column names and rename it .Because i have dataframe which has column names like 'Unnamed 5' etc.and it is tedious to enter such names individually.

Comment: Then the second approach using zip should do as you want @nona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of already having a dictionary, you can use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to map to the new axis values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(10))
d = {5:'five', 6:'six', 7:'seven', 8:'eight'}
df = df.rename(d, axis=1)
# Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 9], dtype='object')
```

Or, as @ch3ster points out, rename takes both `index` and `column` parameters allowing to rename both independently:

```
df = df.rename(columns=d)
```

In the case you know the range of columns to rename, and have a list of new column names, you could build a dictionary as and `rename` with:

```
l = ['five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(range(5,9), l)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the creds ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `rename` with a `dict`, as you mentioned, you could also try renaming the columns this way:

```py
column_names = list(df.columns)
column_names[4:8] = ['five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight']
df.columns = column_names
```

As has already been mentioned though, you don't have to rename one column at a time with the `dict`. You can do them all at once:

```py
my_dict = {5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven'} # etc.
df.rename(columns = my_dict, inplace = True)
```

Comment: The list has 5 elements, the slice your assigning to, `column_names[4:8]`, 4. There will be a length missmatch as a result

Answer (score 0):

Building on the premise of your statement `I don't want to enter the keys in the dictionary individually.`:

You can use a module called [`num2words`](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/).

From the docs:

> num2words is a library that converts numbers like `42` to words like `forty-two`.

Usage:

```
from num2words import num2words
num2words(10)
```

Output:

```
ten
```

Do `pip install num2words`

**Your final code should be:**

```
from num2words import num2words

d = {i: num2words(i) for i in range(100)} 
df = df.rename(d, axis=1)
```